# Hosting an .apk file on over own site

Tags: android, url, apk

I got requirement to host my `.apk` file on one public site other than android market or any other app stores. In android market, after registred in to the market the downloded `.apk` will automatically installed on mobile without any manual action. So I am willing to create one URL and host my `.apk` file in to that and want to download that `.apk` in to the android mobile and it has to install automatically.

How can I do that....plz share if any code or links are there regrading this.

Answer (score 5):

If Android device has Settings->Applications->Unknown Sources checked, Android will allow `.apk` installation. If its not checked - you will not succeed.

Assuming that check bar is checked and you have downloaded `.apk` file. You can run next code to trigger installation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(apkFileName));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i might be missing something simple; but how do i run this code (allowing me to get an application onto my device) so i can code onto my device?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
        String url = "http://www.server.com/yourapp.apk";
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, "yourapp.apk");
        downloadFile(url, outputFile);
        installApp(context);
}



private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException",e+"");
        return; 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException",e+"");
        return; 
    }
}


private static void installApp(Context mycontext) {
    Intent installer = new Intent();
    installer.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String PATH = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/yourapp.apk";
    installer.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(PATH), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    mycontext.startActivity(installer);
}
```

Comment: getContentLength returns the content length in bytes specified by the *response header* field content-length or -1 if this field is not set. There is no guarantee that you will be provided with the correct value.