# Rails' send_file to make apk file being installed

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make my website sending Android `APK` files with some pre-validation so the user just clicks the link and the application starts to install on the device.

The point is, i'm using the `thin` webserver, `send_file path, :type => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive', :disposition => "attachment"`, set the header `headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'` and checked the **Allow untrusted sources** box at the device' settings. But the *apk* file is just downloaded instead of being installed.

**UPD:** The following trouble issues on Android 4 only. My Galaxy S with Android 2.3.6 works fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: For obvious security reasons, I doubt that it is possible to trigger the installation of an APK by simply clicking a link a web page. User will still have to click on the downloaded APK to install it.

Comment: @Sebastien contra: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211416/hosting-an-apk-file-on-over-own-site

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: the question you refer to is basically the same as yours, and there is no correct answer to it. Both answers assume that the user wants to install the APK from another app, whereas what you want is the user to be able to install the APK from the Android browser.

Comment: @Sebastien okay, here's the more concrete link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328459/apk-installation-from-web-page

Comment: @Sebastien please, comment/answer only if there's no solution **for sure** or you do have a solution. Or just do not write at all either. I am sorry if that sounds rude but i think that is the _how to be polite rule_.

Comment: I would really like to test this on my 2.3.6 device, because I consider this a rather big security breach in Android. By any chance could you post a link to a test apk file ?